# How to disable Bullet in ActionMailer previews

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to disable the `Bullet gem` when previewing emails using `ActionMailer::Preview`.  In the Bullet readme, there is an instructon on how do to this for a controller, but how do I apply this to my ActionMailer previews? In my app, the previews are configured to appear at

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/mailers_previews/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I have added the following to my `config/environments/development.rb`

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = false
    pp 'Bullet Disabled'  unless Bullet.enable?
    ... other settings ...
  end
```

The warning is so I do not forget to set `Bullet.enable = true` when I have finished working on my action mailer previews.  You need to restart the server to enable/disable Bullet.